# How i can read multiple child from database Firebase using DialogFlow?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I'm having trouble reading Firebase 'real database' data.

I created an intent with the parameter `$nomeProf`. When I pass a value and try to query in db a "Webhook call failed occurs.

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Access to database is working, I just can't read the children.

I'm trying to get the email pass unique id in dialogflow consoles, example:

`'qual o email do faria?', $nomeProf=faria`.

'faria' and 'correa' are my unique like ID:

[image: 'faria' and 'correa' are my unique like ID]

```
function getProfessorHandler (agent){
  //let nomeProf = agent.parameters.nomeProf; #I need something like this?
  return admin.database().ref("Professor").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    const value = snapshot.child("nomeProf").val();
    const email = value.email;  
    if(value !== null){
      agent.add(`O email é:  ${email}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to load a single child of `Professor` from the database, based on the `agent.parameters.nomeProf` value.

That'd be something like this:

```
return admin.database().ref("Professor").child(agent.parameters.nomeProf).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  const value = snapshot.val();
  const email = value.email;  
  if(value !== null){
    agent.add(`O email é:  ${email}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank u soo much! Working perfectly.